# telerik GridEditCommandColumn + pass row index to another page

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I have a web form, **mypage.aspx** and I use a **Radgrid** to bind data from an entity data model using a linq to entities query.

In my **RadGrid** i have 2 columns that get data from my entities model and an **"Edit"** column (**telerik:GridEditCommandColumn**).

When i click on **Edit** i want to pass the **Id** for the specific record in a new page, **MydetailsPage.aspx**. In that page I want to edit the specific row and save the record. I want to pass the **id** as a query string from **mypage.aspx** to **MydetailsPage.aspx**. Then i need to pass that id in the Linq to entities query in **MydetailsPage.aspx**  in order to retrieve the data.

In **MydetailsPage.aspx** page I have 2 textbox web server controls that I need to bind the values from columns "SystemName" and "Title" from **mypage.aspx**.

thanks

```
  <MasterTableView  EditMode="EditForms" AllowFilteringByColumn="False" AllowSorting="False" DataKeyNames="Id" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>


                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="SystemName" HeaderText="SystemName" SortExpression="SystemName"
                    UniqueName="SystemName">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                 <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title"
                    UniqueName="Title">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn ButtonType="LinkButton" UniqueName="EditCommandColumn" >
                </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn >


            </Columns>
            <EditFormSettings>
                <EditColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" />
            </EditFormSettings>
        </MasterTableView>


</telerik:RadGrid>
```